# Installing check_logfiles Nagios plugin

Tags: nagios

i want to install the [check_logfiles](http://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_logfiles/) Nagios plugin.

The installation step says that

> After unpacking the tar-archive you have to call `./configure`. With `./configure --help` you can show the options if you want to modify the default settings. However, these settings can later be overridden again by variables in the config file.

I am confused that whether I have to do that on monitoring host or remote host for which I want to check log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation of nagios plug-ins take place on the nagios server. It is not clear from your link how to process remote logs with the plug-in, however.

Oh wait, it mentioned being called from check_nrpe - and nrpe is a method of executing remote checks. So it seems that you compile this plug-in on your remote server (the one containing the logs) and it gets executed from the nrpe daemon on that host. See the [sourceforce PDF on NRPE](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf).

First, get nrpe working between your nagios server and your host. Then try and get this plug-in working on your host.

Answer (score 1):

To check remote logfiles you must call the check at the remote host through nrpe or ssh. Nrpe is the best option, ssh checks are more costly.

Other option is forward all your syslog messages to a central syslog server. If the nagios host is the central syslog server for your environment, then you can call the check locally, obviously, because you will have the logs of the remote machine at the nagios server.

Answer (score 0):

From the given examples, it looks like the plugin needs to run on the host whose log files you want to check; so your monitoring host will have (probably) to call this plugin via a SSH session to the monitored host.

But I really can't tell you any better, as I don't speak deutsch...